# How can I tell google script where to print in sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a silly question I somehow can't solve. I'm working in a script where data is printed in a google sheet.

Somehow the printed data is relative to the active cell. How do I set the active cell to be A1? I want to be able to print in the sheet relative to A1.

```
  if (values[i][3] == "1") { 
    var location = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().offset(0,2).getA1Notation();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(location).setValue("LOCAL ("+localcountrycode+")").setFontWeight("bold"); 

  }
```

Comment: I don't understand why getRange("A1") doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eugene is correct, instead of `getActiveCell().offset(...` you should have `getRange("A1").offset(....`, and you don't need the `getA1Notation` either. Then in the next line you can just say `location.setValue(...` You don't need to access the active cell if you are hard coding where the data goes!